# What is the fastest way of indexing to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We've been working with ElasticSearch 2.x for a quite while. Everything meets our requirements perfectly except for one weak point: The performance of writing/indexing to ElasticSearch cluster is not very good.

In our case, we have 8 nodes ES cluster, it's 100~ fields wide indices we are putting in ES. The indexing rate is around 50,000 per minute which is way too slow for our scenario. We've tried all tuning methods recommended by www.elastic.co. The fastest way we've found is that construct the json payload as files, they dump them into ES using bulk API. But still, the indexing pace is just too slow.

I've seen some ES-Hadoop  connector, also elasticsearch has spark support where you can use saveToES() saves the RDD to ES. I suspect they all use ES bulk API underneath. Can anyone share some experience on them? What is the fastest way of writing indices in ElasticSearch?

Comment: The information you provided is not that relevant. Is your cluster all about indexing speed, or are you also doing heavy or frequent searches? What "tuning methods" have you tried?

Comment: @AndreiStefan my question is really about is there any other way we can load data into ES faster than bulk API?

Comment: No matter what third party tool you use outside ES, everything needs to use the ES ways of putting data in. Either Spark, Logstash, your own app all need to use bulk or index api in one way or another. There's no backdoor magic here.

Comment: And the fastest way I know is bulk API.

Comment: @AndreiStefan we've tried to disable the replica while loading indices and also used bulk API, also refresh_interval=-1. While we are heavily write data to ES, we make sure there is very few other r/w against the cluster. Any other tuning I should try to improve the indexing performance.

Comment: You have SSDs or spinning disks?

Comment: The whole cluster is running on the private cloud, underneath it's using ceph on top of JBODs.

Comment: Hmm, have you checked the ceph storage for any IO level recoveries that might be running causing IO wait and thus slowness in the cluster overall? Apart from the slow indexing you report, are there any issues with the cluster? (nodes leaving the cluster from time to time)

Comment: Software-wise, using bulk API is the right way. You could also setup mapping and disable dynamic mapping. Another possibility is to setup [dedicated master node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html). The bottleneck could also come from the hardware. Elasticsearch suggests to have 64GB instances with AT MOST 32GB assigned to the heap. You shall reference [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/hardware.html) for more hardware suggestion. I am also tuning a small ELK cluster. Hope the information helps! :)

Comment: A few more indexing tuning tips: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-performance.html

Comment: Can you make refresh_interval=-1s before starting the indexing and once the indexing is completed you can set it back to default. Refresh interval will Increase your indexing speed very much.Below is the link to know about refresh Interval https://sematext.com/blog/2013/07/08/elasticsearch-refresh-interval-vs-indexing-performance/

Comment: @premkumar We've already tuned refresh_interval=-1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No matter what third party tool you use outside ES, everything needs to use the ES ways of putting data in. Either Spark, Logstash, your own app all need to use bulk or index api in one way or another. There's no backdoor magic here.